Examples of chemical reactions which are spontaneous and have a positive ΔS change, but are also endothermic
We have learnt that the change in the Gibbs Free energy is an indicator that is used to determine whether a chemical reaction is spontaneous or not (at constant temperature and pressure), through the formula:
ΔG= ΔH -TΔS.
I would like examples of thermodynamically spontaneous chemical reactions and are endothermic.

a common example is the many spontaneous endothermic dissolution reactions. Just search on "endothermic dissolution" for examples.

Do you think that positive standard heat of reaction implies positive standard entropy change of reaction?

@Andrew I wanted a more (is proper the right word?) chemical reaction as an example and not a dissolution reaction.

The whole problem with this question is, that there are way too many examples for endothermic reactions. There are plenty of examples in common textbooks. You can even start on Wikipedia, which links a few resources: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endothermic_process I doubt you'll be able to salvage that question by making it more narrow. Sorry.

When some solid sodium bicarbonate is thrown into an $1$ M $\ce{HCl}$ solution, $\ce{CO2}$ is produced spontaneously, so the entropy of the system grows. But the temperature of the acidic solution decreases, which shows that the reaction is endothermic. $$\ce{NaHCO3 + HCl -> NaCl + H2O + CO2}$$ This reaction can also be written netween ions. $$\ce{HCO3^- + H^+ -> H2O + CO2}$$ or $$\ce{HCO3^- + H3O+ -> 2 H2O + CO2}$$As a consequence Delta $\ce{G}$ of the reaction is negative, and Delta $\ce{H}$ of the same reaction is positive. This is apparently what LordofMordor is wanting.

can you give some source for proof that NaHCO3+HCl⟶NaCl+H2O+CO2 has a positive change in enthalpy? I'm not able to find any reliable sources that give data regarding the enthalpy change. (I don't mean to sound snobbish or anything like that). Thanks.

I am unable to give a source for the reaction $$\ce{NaHCO3 + HCl -> NaCl + H2O + CO2}$$ But ti is an experiment that I have carried out plenty of times in all my classes to show qualitatively an endothermic reaction. Whatever the precise concentration, you choose a beaker half filled with any HCl solution. You put a thermometer in this solution. And you add some amounts of $\ce{NaHCO3}$- Whatever their respective amounts, the thermometer initially at around $25$°C, gets down about maybe $5 - 20$°C. This is a convincing example of a endothermic reaction for high school students.

So we need to break a weak bond (endothermic) and make more (gas phase) molecules than we started with. One possibility is
$$\ce{2 NO2Cl(g) <=> 2 NO2(g) + Cl2(g)}$$
for which $\Delta_\mathrm{r}H^\ominus = \pu{41.2 kJ mol-1}$, $\Delta_\mathrm{r}S^\ominus = \pu{158.9 J K-1 mol-1}$ and $\Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\ominus = \pu{-6.2 kJ mol-1}$.
The weak bond here is presumably N-Cl and we make 3 molecules from 2. Even so $\Delta_\mathrm{r}G^\ominus$ is only slightly negative. (A more detailed analysis of all the bonds is really required, since we do make a new Cl-Cl bond, which works against us.)
Raw data from NBS tables, J. Phys. Chem. Ref. Data, v 11, 1982, suppl 2:
$\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\ominus (\ce{NO2Cl}) = \pu{12.6 kJ mol-1}$,
$\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\ominus (\ce{NO2Cl}) = \pu{54.4 kJ mol-1}$,
$S^\ominus (\ce{NO2Cl}) = \pu{272.15 J K-1 mol-1}$.
$\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\ominus (\ce{NO2}) = \pu{33.18 kJ mol-1}$,
$\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\ominus (\ce{NO2}) = \pu{51.31 kJ mol-1}$,
$S^\ominus (\ce{NO2}) = \pu{240.06 J K-1 mol-1}$.
$\Delta_\mathrm{f}H^\ominus (\ce{Cl2}) = \pu{0 kJ mol-1}$,
$\Delta_\mathrm{f}G^\ominus (\ce{Cl2}) = \pu{0 kJ mol-1}$,
$S^\ominus (\ce{Cl2}) = \pu{223.066 J K-1 mol-1}$.
